# Integer as an condition in C++'s " :?" operator

Tags: c++

So , for my exam I have to evaluate some C++ expressions.
Here s the expression :

```
float x=3<<2>>1?4.:.5?6:7>8;
```

Can someone explain it with words because I can t understand it.
So , I have to convert 3 to binary and shift it 2 bits. But After conversion the result is 11. I may add the bit sign so it becomes 011. And after the bit sign I can add as many 0's as i need and so 3<<2-> 01100. But after that I can't understand a thing.. Where s the condition on the conditional operator ?: because I can't see any? 
Thank you in advice for helping me solve this out :)

Comment: Remember that in C++ any non-zero integer value evaluates to `true`.

Comment: This exam question is just silly.  Nobody ever writes code like that.

Comment: Don't worry about understanding it.  The code will never pass code review and the dev has been "deleted" ;). I get they want to test on syntax understanding but that example is just laughable.

Comment: Look at the C++ operator precedence table, add parens to group things appropriately.  Mind the left-to-right and right-to-left associativity.  I would not be surprised if there is a website that will parenthesize the operations of a C++ expression for you.

Comment: As a test question it's remarkably ineffective for determining programming knowledge. One can have the grouping order of the shift operations wrong and still get the correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's format this a little better:

```
float x = (3 << 2) >> 1 ? 4. :
                     .5 ? 6  : 
                      (7 > 8);
```

Or even *better:*

```
float x;
if( 3<<2>>1 ) {
    x = 4.;
} else if( .5 ) {
    x = 6;
} else {
    x = 7 > 8;
}
```

Walking through the evaluation of `3 << 2 >> 1`:

```
(3 << 2) >> 1      =>
(b0011 << 2) >> 1  =>
b1100 >> 1         => 
b0110              =>
6
```

Since 6 is a nonzero value (which evaluates to `true` in C++) **`x` will have the value `4`.**

Answer (score 4):

The expression is

```
3<<2>>1?4.:.5?6:7>8
```

Let's add some spaces and parens:

```
((3 << 2) >> 1) ? 4. : (.5 ? 6 : (7 > 8))
```

Shifting by 1 is just multiplying by 2. Shifting by 2 is multiplying by 2, twice.

So `3 << 2` is `12`.

`12 >> 1` divides by 2, so that's just `6`.

As a condition, all integers (except `0`) are `true`, so this simply returns `4.0`.